# jQueryUi Tabs but using different URL's

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am currently using jQueryUI Tabs on my price comparison / free listings website as I really like the look of them, however on category pages such as this on

http://www.shopseekers.co.uk/category/546/1/womens-jewellery

I have used the tabs to separate the regular retail price comparison listings from users free listings, however instead of loading all the content from both tabs I would like to separate the content into 2 URLs, this is because there will be page 1-40 for regular listings and then page 1-40 for private listings.

Rather than loading page 1 of private listings with every page of regular listings (which will look like duplicate content to Google) it would be so much more easier to just separate the 2. Does anyone know how this can be done while keeping it SEO friendly (ideally without using JavaScript), I've tried just changing the `href="#tabs-2"` to the desired URL but it just seems to load that URL into a frame within the tabs.

Sorry if I've not explained it too clearly but hopefully you'll see what I mean.

Comment: hard to make sense of what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off... You probably shouldn't use tabs at all.  For what you're wanting to accomplish it would be much simpler to use links that you style to look the same as what you have.  Everything you say you want to change is essentially everything that the tabs do.

That being said a possible solution would be to set a click function that would use history.PushState() to change the url, however it should be noted that there is currently limited browser support for it. It is not supported in IE9-.  Depending on how you implemented it, it could fail fairly gracefully if the browser being used doesn't support this functionality.

For reference on the use of history.PushState() see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't think I could but I just managed to sort it out by just changing the elements classes to the jqueryui classes, changing the URL's of the links and removing the code that enables the tabs.